# Simultaneous equations and instrument selection

Tags: self-study, econometrics, simulation, endogeneity

The demand curve

$$P_i= b_1 +b_2 q_i +b_3p_{sub,i}+b_4p_{com,i}+b_5w_i+u_{i1}$$

The supply curve

$$P_i= a_1 +a_2 q_i +a_3p_{sub,i}+a_4p_{com,i}+a_5w_i+u_{i1}$$

Which instruments would you use to instrument $q_i$ in each of the two equations? And which restriction should I apply in order to estimate first one as demand and second one as supply curve?

$p_{sub,i}$ is the price of the substitute of the good i

$p_{com,i}$ is the price of the complement of the good i

$w_i$ the wage

$p$ the price of the good i

$q$ is the quantity of good i.

My idea is that (maybe it is wrong. I am not sure)

In the demand equation, wage is the instrument to q.

In the supply curve, $p_{com}$ is the instrument to q.

What do you think?

Comment: Are you told to choose an instrument only from the variables presented?

Comment: Yes I want to choose one instrument for P and one instrument for Q from the given variables wage comp price and sub price. @Aksakal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is a self-study question, so my answer will be incomplete. You can get a lot of intuition by drawing the supply and demand curves and noting that you only observe the intersections. So in order to trace out the demand, you need something that moves supply up and down, but does not move around demand at the same time (here price is on the x axis, unlike your equation which has it as the outcome):

[image]

Similarly logic for the supply.

Typically, variation in costs will move around supply since that is essentially a marginal cost curve, so wages seem to be a good candidate. That implies something about $a_5$. But then wages cannot enter into the demand equation (say because the workers consume more of the output when they make more money), and that has some implication about $b_5$.

Comment: Thank you so much.well please explain, which instruments should be used for $q$ in each question? I don’t understand that part.

Comment: There's the skeleton of an answer in the last paragraph, but I cannot do your homework for you. If you want wages to move the supply curve and higher wages lead to higher prices, what do you think has to be true of $a_5$ coefficient?

Comment: That’s wage is my instrument for P in supply curve. So $a5\not= 0$ . And $b5=0$. Do I understand correct from your explanation?

Comment: Well, what about the instrument for Q ? since both $P_{com}$ and $P_{sub}$ affect the demand, both are instrument for Q ? Then can I say for instrument to Q?

Comment: Sorry this is not homework. These are past exam sets and since I completed pure statistics, I cannot understand this economic part. So I asked in detail. Thank you for your helps. You are giving really great explanation

Comment: You restrictions on parameters makes sense. What has to be the analogous restrictions for the demand equation?

Comment: $P_{sub}$ is my instrument to Q (demand) in demand equation. So a3=0 but $   b3\not=0$ Right? dear Masterov.

Comment: You figured it out.

Comment: Correct or false? I am stuck with the choose of instrument for demand. Q. I guess if price of substitute increases then people want to buy substitute goods and don’t want to buy real goods. So I can change demand curve by changing substitute price.

Comment: Then substitute price is instrument for Q in demand curve.

Comment: Yes, but you also need the coefficient in the supply equation to be zero. You can have firms alter output of the main good when the price of a substitute good falls.

Comment: Then as you said, a3=0 in order for the coefficient in supply curve to be zero. And by relevance condition $b3 \not= 0$. Now is it more correct ?

Comment: That is perfect.